# Kendo UI Splitter getsize(), getPosition()

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-splitter

I am programming an webpage with Kendo UI which is customizable by the user.
Now I want to save the layout, so the server can send the user his last layout.

I use the Kendo UI widget Splitter. How do I get the position of the splitter.
You can set the size of the panes with the methode called size(), but how do I get the value.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/splitter#methods-size

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#splitter").kendoSplitter();
var splitter = $("#splitter").data("kendoSplitter");

//use jquery & target ids
console.log($('#paneA').width(), $('#paneB').width());    

//use jquery and get all panes info
$('#splitter > .k-pane').each(function(id, item) {
   console.log( $(item).html(), $(item).width() ); 
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2n5vpt8s/)